# Getting an "Unexpected reserved word 'await' " error when using Firestore setDoc Method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following this documentation:
[Firestore Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEPaZ.png)

my code:

```
import { setDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";

const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await setDoc(
        doc(db, "messages", "test"),
        {
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          message: message,
          created: Date.now(),
        }
      );
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
```

I'm using react, and getting this error:
"Unexpected reserved word 'await' "

Comment: my node version is 12.x.x.x

Comment: `await` is only valid in `async` functions (and since node v14.8 in top-level code of modules). The anonymous function you assigned to `sendMessage` is _not_ declared `async`. (And when you change that, make sure the _caller_ of `sendMessage` is aware of that too and `await`s it or at least calls `.catch` on its return value to do error handling.)

Comment: Not much context to go here but yeah, `sendMessage` needs to be declared `async` so the `await` keyword is valid in the function scope. To add to CherryDT's comment about the caller possibly needing to be made aware of the change, this is because `async` functions ***implicitly*** return a Promise, so callers need to also wait for the Promise to resolve, or use a Promise chain.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you!